# NSCoding Prebundle Data

Tags: objective-c, bundle, nscoding

I am using NSCoding to save a serialized list of my object. This object's successfully saved in the path:

/var/mobile/Applications/F923C87-360D-4B429-B2E9-CAE121009ECE5/Documents/feed_file

And I can get the object successfully when the app starts.

I'm looking to deploy the app with some contents already loaded, so I want to have a primary version of `feed_file` in the apps.

How can I do that, copy it the first time the app starts but not the other times?

Answer (score 0):

Put a bit of code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, check whether there is any file at the destination path (`Documents/feed_file`), if there isn't then copy the default file out of the bundle. The default file should be part of the Xcode project and copied to the bundle during the build.